# How do I allow public access to a php script with certain get values on an htpasswd restricted site?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, matomo

This is my first question on here.

I am using Piwik web analytics for tracking on my PHP-based site. I would like people to be able to see the public opt-out option, the tracking script (of course) and one of the widgets. I have made the whole site public, but I find anyone being able to see people's browsing data kind of weird.

Since you cannot make just one widget public in Piwik as yet, I am using the "back door" way and using .htaccess and htpasswords to achieve that.

At the moment I have got public access to the tracking script enabled very easily with:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/piwik.js" allow
```

Which works like a charm.

What I can't seem to work out how to do (and have tried many ways) is how to allow unrestricted access to:
 `/index.php?module=CoreAdminHome&action=optOut&language=en` (opt-out code)
and
 `/index.php?module=Widgetize&action=iframe&widget=1&moduleToWidgetize=Live&actionToWidgetize=getSimpleLastVisitCount&idSite=1&period=day&date=yesterday&disableLink=1&widget=1`

It seems to be because it has get directives on there. Is there any way I can do this, without making index.php all public (the whole of piwik seems to run off index.php).

Comment: Can you try to explain your problem a bit more.

Comment: I want to allow access to the two files I mentioned, but I cannot figure out how to allow access to files with certain GET parameters, only to index.php as a whole.

Comment: Can you place your current .htaccess in your question for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can request authentication by adding a couple of request headers. Look here for examples:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php